# Lodash: apply class instance method if instance is not null or undefined

Tags: typescript, lodash

Let's assume we have the following example:

```js
class Person {
  surname: string;
  firstname: string;

  getFullName(separator: string) {
    return this.surname + separator + this.firstname;
  }
}

const person = ...

const fullName = _.ifNotNull(person, value => value.getFullName('-'));
```

Is there an equivalent to the `ifNotNull` function in [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) which would apply a method from the object parameter only if it is not null or undefined?

Comment: You don't need lodash. `person?.getFullName('-')`

Comment: @MoshFeu you mean ``person?person.getFullName('-'):default ?``
It think it could be more clean with function like _.ifNotNull

Comment: No, he means `person?.getFullName`, it's called [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html). Trying to use a function to achieve what's already been built-in seems pointless. It doesn't look cleaner, it look like a waste of time.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtNYAtvAFzQQAuiAlmgObQC80A5CwNy7QBm1yFBYmUo16TVh2xc68CgDEAriBAA5IvAAUEeAAcwiMBRSJhVWnQCUWLnkSyFiDBQAW1CADpB8aAGpyu-UNjX2gXN3defi9OPABfbHjsYHRKaB0kVAxmYDtDeARkdA0LTmS0VPTCtAAmcRz4PILMjRYAK3QWEqSUlBB4dxAUOg1KzIB+dxl5JVV1FoBaTq6y1D6BoZGM9GqJqcVlNWIFpc5sbgU0YApqdGh6xq20DS8x01FLazxqbmhn9SscHg8CsKGlxGh4AB3OCPYoxIE6TzqcHqeG2eyONLw+LoigODBoGacWJAA

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Well I am working with angular 8 which require TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0, but  Optional Chaining are only supported by typescript@3.7.0-beta and above, so I can't use it right now

Answer (score 0):

## You can use Lodash

As a matter of fact, Lodash has got the function you are looking for, it's called [`_.invoke`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#invoke). In your example above, you could write:

```
const fullName = _.invoke(person, "getFullName", "-");
```

And it would work just as expected. So, how does `_.invoke` work?

- `_.invoke` has got the following signature: `_.invoke(object, path, [args])`. It invokes the method at path (which could be a nested path as well as just the method name) inside of object, with `this` binded to the object.

### Can I quickly try it in the browser?

Of course! I made a Codepen where you can try this and other ways to do the same thing directly in your browser. Just remember to open the browser console to see the test results! Here is the link, you can find `_.invoke` in `testcase1a()` and `testcase1b()`:

https://codepen.io/jhack_jos/pen/ExNVbWp

### How does the expression above resolve?

1. If `person` is undefined or `person` does not have a method called `getFullName` the expression  `_.invoke(person, "getFullName", "-");` resolves like this:

```js
    //STEP 1
    const fullName = _.invoke(person, "getFullName", "-");

    //STEP 2
    const fullName = undefined;
```

2. if `person` is defined, and has got a `getFullName` method:

```js
    //STEP 1
    const fullName = _.invoke(person, "getFullName", "-");

    //STEP 2
    const fullName = person.getFullName("-");

    //STEP 3
    const fullName = "surname-firstname";
```

### Warning

If `person` has got a property that is not a method called `getFullName`, you will get a runtime error!!